# filenotfound error python (running through atom)

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm working my way through the python crash course pdf. Everything was going well until I hit chapter 10 "files and exceptions".
The task is very simple.
1) create a text file "pi_digits.txt" that contains the first 30 digits of pi.
2) run the following code:

```
    with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
        contents = file_object.read()
        print(contents)
```

I keep getting a filenotfounderror [errno 2].

I have tried using the full file path, placing the file in the same ~.atom folder that contains the package 'script'.

I tried to run the file through a terminal and got the same error message.
I also searched stackoverflow for solutions and did find similar problems but the answers did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try specifying the full path: `with open('/path/to/pi_digits.txt') as ...`

Comment: Try placing your file parallel to your script containing `if __name__ ==  '__main__':`.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend this:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('/tmp')
```

and copy the .txt file to /tmp. Also, be sure the copied filename is all lowercase, to match your program.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.